# Importing hundreds of CSV's into postgres (non-sequential naming)

Tags: postgresql

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132569/loading-multiple-csv-files-into-postgresql-table

Looked at links like this, but it doesn't really make sense to me.  Is there any way anyone could dumb this down for me?  I'm using ubuntu btw.  Thank you!

Comment: your loink is for wndows shell, you must look for bash

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770591/importing-and-maintaining-multiple-csv-files-into-postgresql . Okay found this, does this look right?

Comment: no this is for r another programming language you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736762/script-to-automat-import-of-csv-into-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

If the CSV files are in the same directory, a global import can be scripted from  Ubuntu with a bash script like:

```
cd /path/to/csv-directory
for file in *.csv
do
  psql (add connection options here) << EOF
\copy MyTableName from $file (format csv)
EOF
done
```